# formvalidation.io form validation. If "other", please explain

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation, jquery-form-validator

I'm using the FormValidation plugin in Bootstrap and am loving it, except I can't figure out one thing.  I have a form with an "other" check box.  If you check "other", I want an explanation typed into another field.  I've been all over the website (formvalidation.io), but I'm not finding an answer.  Unfortunately, I know just enough JS to be dangerous.

Here's the code for the validator I'm using on the check boxes.

```
'work_type[]': {
    validators: {
    choice: {
        min: 1,
        message: 'Please choose at least one work type.'
    }
    }
}
```

There's another field called "other_work" that I would like to require a string in if work_type has a value of "Other Work".

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to figure this out check out [callback functions](http://formvalidation.io/validators/callback/)

You declare your own function something like this:

```
function optionOtherValidator(value) {         
    if ($('#amountOther input').is(':checked');) {
        return /^\w+$/.test(value);
    }

    return true;
},
```

Then in your fields array you declare it as a callback:

```
fields: {
    optionOther: {
        validators: {
            callback: {
                message: 'Please specify a value for other',
                callback: optionOtherValidator
            }
        }
    }
...
```